# Magnetic susceptibility in 1/eV

Tags: electromagnetism, unit-conversion

In [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2207v4) paper the authors refer to

> transverse susceptibility $\chi_{ \perp}$ [meV $^{−1}$]

I was taught that the magnetic susceptibility is dimensionless.

How do I get $\chi$ in the above units??

Answer (score 1):

Magnetic susceptibility is a static constant relating the amount of magnetization to the applied magnetic field; it is dimensionless.  Transverse susceptibility is a measure of the magnetic response of a material to an alternating field; it is not dimensionless. The transverse susceptibility is often used when talking to the ferromagnetic resonance (like I think they are doing in the paper you cite) of a material.

So the short answer is that MS is dimensionless and TS is not.